# Add wParam and lParam Parameter to WM_QUERYENDSESSION handler

Tags: windows, mfc

I want to distinguish in `QueryEndSession` if Window will be restarted or just logging Off.
The default handler signature for `WM_QUERY_END_SESSION` by Class Wizard is:

```
afx_msg BOOL OnQueryEndSession();
```

I want to extend this to or similiar

```
LRESULT MyOnQueryEndSession(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

In the documentation for [QueryEndSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/wm-queryendsession) there is a WindowProc funtion

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( 
  HWND hwnd,      // handle to window 
  UINT uMsg,      // message identifier 
  WPARAM wParam,  // not used 
  LPARAM lParam   // logoff option
);
```

So, I think this is possible, but I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: What are you really trying to do by distinquishing between "logging out" and "logging out and rebooting"? The user could still logout and reboot from the login screen.

Comment: You are not required to use the premade `ON_WM_QUERYENDSESSION`. You can use `ON_MESSAGE` and provide a custom handler.

Comment: @RaymondChen ON_MESSAGE works, thanks.

Comment: @selbie, I want to distinguish, if an automatic reboot  was initiated, so my app goes on the state before  it was rebooted.